# Android: Stopping program flow from continuing if error condition?

Tags: android, validation, android-intent

Within my activity I am trying to use `validation` within a method (shown below) to carry out two functionalities:

1. Display toast as error message if there is an error condition
2. Bring user back to main menu using intents.

The above is working however after the validation is carried out the `program flow` within that activity is still being carried out. (see second code block below).

How can I ensure that nothing else in the activity is executed after, if the validation block is called in my method? I.e. just return to MainMenu, dont execute rest of code in `finally` block.

**Method containing validation:**

```
public void getAverageAttentionValue() {

        // validation to ensure that no dividing by zero
        if (totalofAttLevels < 1) {

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    StroopGame.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //display error message
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    StroopGame.this,
                                    "Headset unable to read values, please re-connect",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    Intent openActivity = new Intent(
                                            "com.example.brianapp.MainMenu");
                                    startActivity(openActivity);

                                    device.close();
                                }
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();

        } else {

            averageAttLevel = totalofAttLevels / attCount;

            attMax = Collections.max(AttentionValues);
        }



    }
```

**Calling the above method in finally block and the code that is still being called afterwards:**

```
                     finally {
                       //calling method containing validation
                       getAverageAttentionValue();


                        //I DONT WANT THE CODE BELOW TO BE EXECUTED IF 
                        //THE VALIDATION IN METHOD IS CALLED

                        // write data from session to SQLite db
                        writeToDatabase();
                        // stop audio
                        tenSecs.stop();
                        // declaring activity to open
                        Intent openActivity = new Intent(
                                "com.example.brianapp.StroopResults");
                        openActivity.putExtra("singleScore", single);
                        // Start activity
                        startActivity(openActivity);

                        device.close();

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as :
Take a member variable for e.g `boolean isValidateCalled = false;` in the your activity. Then set that variable to `true` if your `validate()` method is called. And then in `finally`

```
              finally {
                       //calling method containing validation
                       getAverageAttentionValue();
                        // Check whether validate was called,if not,proceed 
                        if(!isValidateCalled)
                        {
                        // write data from session to SQLite db
                        writeToDatabase();
                        // stop audio
                        tenSecs.stop();
                        // declaring activity to open
                        Intent openActivity = new Intent(
                                "com.example.brianapp.StroopResults");
                        openActivity.putExtra("singleScore", single);
                        // Start activity
                        startActivity(openActivity);
                        }
                        device.close();

                    }
```